# Keep POST with rewrite module in htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, post, url-rewriting

I created a PHP function that can get a controller, a model and a view from the uri inserted.

The user indicates an url, exemple : wwww.my-site.com/news/creation
and my .htaccess send the request on my index.php.

In my index.php, my function call the model, controller and view.

It works fine.

But when I submit a form with 'post' dictionnary.

The dictionnary is emptied.

How can I keep it?

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteRule !\.(js|ico|gif|jpg|png|css|html|swf|flv|xml)$ index.php [QSA,L]
```

**EDIT :**

My bug comes from my html, the input in my form did not have 'name' attribute.

Here is the code of my working rewrite :

*.htaccess*

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteRule !\.(js|ico|gif|jpg|png|css|html|swf|flv|xml)$ index.php [QSA,L]
```

*index.php*

```
    $full_url = 'http://'.$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST].$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI];
    $real_uri = str_replace(APPLICATION_PATH, '',$full_url );
    $array_uri = explode('/', trim($real_uri, '/'));
```

Comment: What do you mean by "keep my POST"?

Answer (score 1):

By the definition of redirects, redirecting a post request will not resend the data to the new url. If you want to get the data to a different file on your server, use an internal rewrite instead. If you want to get the data to an url that is not on your server, your server will need to proxy it. **I would recommend to just fix the url your data is posted to, and excempt that url in your rule**.

The rule you posted in your question does not perform a redirect however. If a redirect takes place, the redirect originates from the code in index.php.